# Not able to access variables in RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I am trying to run some sample `RSpec` examples from an ebook but it looks the book is having older version of `RSpec` hence some examples are referencing old `RSpec API` which is creating problems. I am trying to resolve them as much as I can but since I am new to `Ruby` & `RSpec` its a little challenging for me.

From the error log I can figure out that it's a scoping problem but not sure how to resolve it.

Is `subject` still a part of rspec 3.4.2 version?

```
$rspec --version
3.4.2
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
require "spec_helper"
describe Location do
    describe "#initialize" do
        subject { Location.new(:latitude => 38.911268, :longitude => -77.444243) } 
        expect(:latitude).to eq(38.911268)
        expect(:longitude).to eq(-77.444243)
    end
end
```

**Error Log:**

> `method_missing`: `expect` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). (RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong: You're using `except` outside of an example. It must be in an `it` block. P.S. They're still not going to work. The symbol `:latitude` is only equal to `:latitude` (just like the string `"latitude"` is only equal to `"latitude"`). It will never be equal to a number. Perhaps you meant `subject.latitude`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment above states you have some issues with this spec. You could refactor to the following:

```
describe Location do
  describe "#initialize" do
    subject { Location.new(latitude: 38.911268, longitude: -77.444243) } 

    it "longitude & latitude is set" do
      expect(subject.latitude).to eq (38.911268)
      expect(subject.longitude).to eq (-77.444243)
    end
  end
end
```

Here a few points on what's going on:

---

`RSpec explicit subject`

- The docs say: use subject in the group scope to explicitly define the value that is
  returned by the subject method in the example scope.
- You could equally have defined it using `let` like this:
- `let(:location) { Location.new(latitude: 38.911268, longitude: -77.444243) }`
- You would then be using `location` rather than `subject` as the object in your tests.

---

`Describe vs it blocks`

- The docs say: the describe method creates an example group. Within the block passed to
  describe you can declare nested groups using the describe or context
  methods, or you can declare examples using the it or specify methods.
- You can go further and add `context` blocks as well.

  ```
  describe "something" do
    context "in one context" do
      it "does one thing" do
        ###expect something
      end
    end

    context "in another context" do
      it "does another thing" do
        ###expect something else
      end
    end
  end
  ```

Basically any code that `expects` (i.e. your spec's expectation) is always going to sit within an `it` block.

---